# delete many empty spaces between columns and make only one-white-space between columns

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I have a file with more than 2500 columns. Each column is separated with tab or several white space.

The data format in the file is as below:

```
1    1    0
1    1    0
0    1    0
1    0    1
1    0    0
1    1    1
1    0    1
```

I want to delete the tab or many empty white-spaces between the columns and make only one white-space between the columns as below.

```
1 1 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 0 1
```

How I delete the empty spaces ?

Comment: This reproduce the same file. In my actual file there are 27 white spaces between two columns. And there are more than 2500 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' file
1 1 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 0 1
```

By setting `$1=$1` it cleans up all the spaces and tabs. `1` is to print it.

Comment: This is fine for your question since you seem to be primarily interested in knowing how to do this in Awk but it is not very easy to read. If I were coding something that others may need to maintain I would probably go with `sed` or `tr` for readability. Awk can also accomplish this non-intuitive "trick" with several other syntaxes - e.g.  `awk {'$6=$9'}8`

Comment: @A.Danischewski `awk {'$6=$9'}8` this will change the field number  `6` to another value that it have original.  This should do: `awk {'$6=$6'}8 `

Comment: @Jotne Yes, that is true - but since there are only 3 columns in this case it has the same effect as `$1=$1`, and if you do `$6=$2` it will provide another column. Quirky interesting tricks that Awk can do are okay for playing around, but I wouldn't include them in my code if I could avoid it.

Comment: If you want to make it a bit more clear and still use Awk you can use gsub: `awk '{gsub("[ ]+"," ",$0);print}' file`

Comment: @A.Danischewski This also fail for OP since he has also has tab.  Should then be: `awk '{gsub("[ \t]*"," ",$0);print}' file`

Comment: Thanks, my comment was about the idea of using `gsub` to make it more clear about what is going on - to provide an answer to the OP its probably best to use the POSIX character classes `[:blank:]` or `[:space:]`.

Answer (score 4):

With sed:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/ /g' filename
```

Alternatively with tr:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' filename
```

Comment: Since I am dealing with a file containing > 2500 columns and 45000 rows, the "sed" command takes long time. But the "tr -s" rum much faster than "awk".